# How to rigorously determine whether two events are independent?

Tags: probability, intuition, independence

Consider the following question:

> Tim has lost his pet in either forest A (with probability 0.4) or in
>   forest B (with probability 0.6).
>
> If his pet is in forest A and Tim spends a day searching for it in
>   forest A, the conditional probability that he will find his pet that
>   day is 0.25. Similarly, if his pet is in forest B and Tim spends a day
>   looking for it there, he will find the pet that day with probability
>   0.15.
>
> The pet cannot go from one forest to the other. Tim can search only in
>   the daytime, and he can travel from one forest to the other only
>   overnight. Tim stops searching as soon as he finds his pet.
>
> In which forest should Tim look on the first day of the search to
>   maximize the probability he finds his pet that day?

To solve this question, I have defined the following events:

F:  Event that the pet is forest A.                         F':  Event that the pet is in forest B.

Fi: Event that he finds his pet on day i.             Fi': Event that he doesn't find his pet on day i.

Si: Event that he searches forest A on day i.     Si': Event that he searches forest B on day i.

And from the given information, I have constructed the following Venn diagram:

[image: Venn diagram]

The question asks which one of $ P(Fi | Si) $ or $ P(Fi | Si') $ is bigger.

Now as far as I understand, solving the question with only this much information is not possible. I guess that in order to solve the question, I need to assume that Si and F are independent events. *Intuitively*, this is a sound assumption because by the wording of the question, it seems like Tim chooses the forest to search totally *at his own wish*.

When I solve the question using this assumption, I do the algebra and get $ P(Fi | Si) = 0.1 $ and $ P(Fi | Si') = 0.09 $.

Now comes my question: I have assumed that Si and F are independent totally *intuitively*. That is: I have read the question and by the wording of the question and by *common sense*, I have concluded that Si and F must be independent and hence, I was able to solve the question.

However, I am not *exactly sure* whether these two events are *indeed* independent. By common sense and intuition, I have concluded that these events are independent. However, I don't have mathematical arguments, or any kind of argument that is *more rigorous* than *common sense* and *intuition* to back up this assumption.

So my question is this: How can I rigorously determine whether two events are independent?

By the way, note that an argument such as: "To *rigorously* determine whether two events A and B are independent, simply check whether the equation $ P(A \cap B) = P(A) * P(B) $ holds." is totally invalid. Because I want to know whether events A and B are independent in the case that I don't know $ P(A \cap B) $ or $ P(A) $ or $ P(B) $. In other words, I want to know whether two events are independent in order to *make inferences* on $ P(A \cap B) $ or $ P(A) $ or $ P(B) $. Not to *validate my calculations* on $ P(A \cap B) $ and $ P(A) $ and $ P(B) $.

Comment: @Masacroso Could you elaborate? I couldn't quite grasp your comment.

Comment: $S_i$ and $F$ are not independent events because $S_i$ is not a random event.  It is a predetermined choice and you are being asked to make that determination.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Then is my conclusion that $ P(Fi | Si) = 0.1 $ and $ P(Fi | Si') = 0.09 $ wrong? Also, how can we solve this question if Si and F are not independent?

Comment: Sry, I missread the question :p

Answer (score 1):

If Tim searches forest A the probability that he finds the pet that day is: $0.40\cdot 0.25$.   That is: $0.10$

If Tim searches forest B the probability that he finds the pet that day is: $0.60\cdot 0.15$.   That is: $0.09$

Tim searches in forest A first.

Comment: But why? I understood that $0.25$ is the probability for $ P(Fi | F \cap Si) $. Similarly $0.15$ is the probability for $ P(Fi | F' \cap Si') $. If this is correct, then how do we proceed from here to obtain your answer? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Utku remember the law of total probability and that the question is asking what is bigger: $\Pr[F_A]$ or $\Pr[F_B]$, where $F_A$ is find in forest $A$.